# Not able to send transaction using alchemy sdk

Tags: solidity, web3js, alchemy, etherjs, alchemy-sdk

Hey i have to build a ERC20 contract and using alchemy sdk to send transactions onchain
For eg mint or burn tokens. But i am not able to send a transaction as its showing an error of `cannot estimate gas`

```
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS;

// provider - Alchemy
const alchemyProvider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider(network="maticmum", API_KEY);

// signer - you
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, alchemyProvider);

// contract instance
const helloWorldContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI, signer);

async function main() {
    // console.log(helloWorldContract);
    const message = await helloWorldContract.symbol();
    console.log("The message is: " + message); 
    
    const a=await signer.getGasPrice()
    console.log(a.toString());
    
    console.log("Updating the message...");
    const tx = await helloWorldContract.mint(100);
    await tx.wait();
    
    // const message2 = await helloWorldContract.balanceOf(CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    // console.log("The message is: " + message2); 
}

main();
```

And the error i am facing is

```
var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

<ref *1> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT"
```

I have gone through docs but cannot find the reason.

*Chain used - Polygon_mumbai*

Or if there is any other method/framework that can do this other than this sdk, please recommend

Answer (score 0):

Try out web3client.app

[Here](https://workspace.web3client.app/evm?web3ClientToken=50f4540e-e813-48a0-8cac-e2bd762a86ea) is the link to download erc20 directly and you can execute it.

It uses ethers default provider to execute the transaction. Try the code feature to get the working code you are looking for.

This might help you i believe.

Alternatively, you can try hardhat to deploy contract locally before pushing it to prod

[Here](https://youtu.be/NipAzRl4klo) is a small tutorial for it.

Comment: Thanks,@sam but here my mistake was that i din't had enough MATIC on my wallet. So after adding more MATIC it worked fine for me.

Comment: Ok ok got it ✌️